Use date range control for Jalali(Pesian) calendar in Looker Studio
I want to use date range control for the Jalali(Pesian) calendar in Looker Studio,; is there any way? My input date is in Persian format.P
I want to show my users filters in the Jalali format to choose from.
I can use a single date filter on a column, but I want to choose a range.
